# 3 Query by column and create a new table

Tags: sql, list, subquery

I have students, and these students have their meals, morning and evening. I want to print the number of meals each student eats in the morning and evening.

If the number of dishes that student eats in the morning is more than one, I want to print the number in the table and the ID of the food.

FoodType when 1(morning), and when 2(evening)

```
StudentId FoodId FoodType
    3       1       1
    3       2       1
    3       3       1
    3       4       2
    4       3       1
    4       1       2
    4       2       2
    4       4       2
    5       4       2
    5       1       1
    6       1       1
    6       2       1
    6       3       2
    6       4       2
```

Sample out;

```
StudentId  MorningFoodCountOrId  EveningFoodCountOrId
    3             3 meals                 4
    4             3                       3 meals
    5             4                       1
    6             2 meals                 2 meals
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation. The logic that decides if we print the number of records or their value is not intuitive, but I would phrase it as follows:

```
select 
    studentId, 
    case when sum(case when foodtype = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
        then max(case when foodtype = 1 then foodId end) 
        else sum(case when foodtype = 1 then 1 else 0 end)
    end MorningFoodCountOrId
    case when sum(case when foodtype = 2 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
        then max(case when foodtype = 2 then foodId end) 
        else sum(case when foodtype = 2 then 1 else 0 end)
    end EveningFoodCountOrId
from mytable
group by studentId
```

You RDMBS should be able to optimize the query by not computing the conditional sums twice.

Note: you did not specify which RDMBS you are using. If this is MySQL, then it is possible to shorten the conditional sums a little, as follows:

```
select 
    studentId, 
    case when sum(foodtype = 1) = 1
        then max(case when foodtype = 1 then foodId end) 
        else sum(foodtype = 1)
    MorningFoodCountOrId
    case when sum(foodtype = 2) = 1
        then max(case when foodtype = 2 then foodId end) 
        else sum(foodtype = 2)
    EveningFoodCountOrId
from mytable
group by studentId
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query, `select sum()` and `case..` will do this

```
select t1.studentid
    , case when t1.m <= 1 then t2.FoodId else concat(t1.m, ' meals') end MorningFoodCountOrId  
    , case when t1.e <= 1 then t3.FoodId else concat(t1.e, ' meals') end EveningFoodCountOrId

from(
    select studentid
      , sum(case when FoodType = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as m       
      , sum(case when FoodType = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as e        
    from tableA
    group by studentid) t1
left join tableA t2 on t2.studentId = t1.studentId and t1.m = 1 and t2.FoodType = 1
left join tableA t3 on t3.studentId = t1.studentId and t1.e = 1 and t3.FoodType = 2
order by t1.studentid
```

see [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qyKFDidLoLGs6v6WGHrjdG/0#&togetherjs=h90C4RGw1L)

in **postgresql**

```
, case when t1.m <= 1 then t2.FoodId::text else concat(t1.m, ' meals') end MorningFoodCountOrId  
, case when t1.e <= 1 then t3.FoodId::text else concat(t1.e, ' meals') end EveningFoodCountOrId
```